# Простая анимация на jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Плохо знаю Jquery и js в частности. Проблема состоит в том что есть блок с анимацией, анимация должна исчезать при экране шириной скажем `1024px`.

Как сделать такую же анимацию через js?

Код:

```css
.vertical {
  animation: vertical_1049 1.5s ease infinite;
  transform-origin: 75% 75%;
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.2);
  -moz-transform: scale(1.2);
  -ms-transform: scale(1.2);
  -o-transform: scale(1.2);
  transform: scale(1.2);

}
@keyframes vertical_1049 {
  0% { transform:translate(0,0px) }
  50% { transform:translate(0,10px) }
  100% { transform:translate(0,0) }
}
.zoomInBtn{
  -webkit-transform: scale(2.5);
  -moz-transform: scale(2.5);
  -ms-transform: scale(2.5);
  -o-transform: scale(2.5);
  transform: scale(2.5);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s linear;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s linear;
  -ms-transition: all 0.3s linear;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s linear;
  transition: all 0.3s linear;
}
```

```html
<p class="vertical">Sample Text</p>
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qboshnyn/)

Comment: Зачем делать на js то, что можно сделать через css? css быстрее

Answer (score 2):

Как вариант:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
   .vertical {
        display: none;
   }
}
```

Или под словом "исчезать" Вы что-то другое имели в виду?